# Suburl's ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, url-routing, passenger

I'm having a problem using a sub url, when I try to access through authentication page, it generates an authentication cookie, but i keep on login screen and if i try access some page it says that i must got logged.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sub-domain, you have to change, your config/initializer/session_store.rb

And add your subdomain, with a dot before like that :

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_key', :domain => ".yourdomain.com"
```